# Is Firebase App Check available for Unity, Godot, or other game engines?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, godot, ddos, firebase-app-check

I am about to start making a game for iOS/Android which involves connection to Firebase backend.
Since the game contains a bit controversy theme, I'm scared of DDoS kind of attacks.

To make protection, I know Google provides Firebase App Check service and they say it's available for iOS/Android/Flutter/Web according to their webpage.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check

My question is, is the service available for Unity, Godot, or other game engines?
Since App Check SDK is available for Flutter, does this mean we need SDK for Unity, Godot etc. if we use those engines?
Or can we just use Firebase iOS/Android SDK together with any game engine?

I checked whether they provide SDK (with App Check) for any game engine and only found that Firebase Unity SDK seems to be trying to implement App Check feature (but not done yet).
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk/issues/511

Answer (score 0):

It would appear Firebase is available in the [Play Core Native SDK](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/native), so it would be possible to use GDNative to access the API.

Comment: Thank you!  Glad to know it has access to Android, at least.  Hope the similar way also works for iOS too.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the [Reduce cheating with Firebase App Check](https://gamedevsummit.withgoogle.com/events/create-great-games/watch?talk=reduce-cheating-with-firebase-app-check) talk at the Google for Games Developers Summit, App Check is coming to Firebase for C++ and Unity.

Check out the segment at 10:20 where we discuss the process of setting it up in the console and code.